# Create VRT from shapefile using a where clause

Tags: gdalbuildvrt, where-clause

I am wondering if there is a way to create a .vrt using a shapefile, but specifying attributes through a where clause. I have made a .vrt from a sub section shapefile (pre selected the tiles and exported as a new file) using the following:

```
 gdalbuildvrt -tileindex fullpath output.vrt area4.shp
```

But I would like to not have to create new shapefiles based on selected areas, so something like:

```
 gdalbuildvrt -tileindex fullpath WHERE areaid = 4 output.vrt area4.shp
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Create vrt file with gdalbuildvrt and hand edit it afterwards as in the 
`SQLite/Spatialite SQL dialect (GDAL >=1.10.0) example` in the document page of the VRT driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html. What you need to do is to add into the layer definion this:

```
<SrcSQL dialect="sqlite">SELECT * from area4 where areaid=4</SrcSQL>
```

Comment: So would this be a two staged process? Create vrt, then edit? Or is this a single operation?

Comment: With two steps. But I am not sure if it would work because I thought that you were playing with OGR VRT http://www.gdal.org/drv_vrt.html but actually you have rasters http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html. Anyway, you can create a vector vrt with SrcSQL and you that vrt as a tileindex for gdalbuildvrt.